# Выравнивание в reportviewer

Tags: c#

Есть текстовое поле, в котором находится слово постоянной длины "Газета", далее идет поле, значение которого берется из базы данных, соответственно оно может быть разной длины. Как выровнять оба поля по центру страницы?

Comment: Вы не упомянули о какой вообще странице идет речь.

Comment: Хм, а они разные бывают? rdlc документ обычный.

Comment: В конструкторе у каждой ячейки есть свойство TextAlign. Программно можно попробовать добавить пустые отступы методом *.PadLeft();* исходя и числа полученных символов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал проще. Объединил в одно текстовое поле. Получилось вроде этого `="Газета " + First(Fields!Field_name.Value)`